# Не изменяется глобальная переменная в случае с локальной функцией

Tags: python, global-variables

В данном фрагменте кода переменная *var* не изменяется в области видимости `func1`.

```
def func1():
    var = False

    def func2():
        global var
        var = True
        print(var)

    func2()
    print(var)

func1()
```

Результат:

```
True  
False
```

Если объявить *var* в глобальной области видимости, все работает:

```
True
True
```

Подскажите, в чем проблема, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно использовать `nonlocal`.
Оператор `global` ищет переменные только в глобальной зоне видимости,
`nonlocal` - во всех на пути вверх, начиная от ближайшей; исключая глобальную.